# State not updating in react with a nested object (hooks)

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-beautiful-dnd

I've been playing with react-beautiful-dnd and hooks (very new to react) - and for some reason my state doesn't update on drag. (Edit: I know the logic only works for 'same category' drag - this isn't updating the UI either for me)

Data (simplified)

```
const skills = {
  skills: {
    skill1: {
      id: "skill1",
      name: "Communication"
    },
    skill2: {
      id: "skill2",
      name: "Empathy"
    },
    skill3: {
      id: "skill3",
      name: "Initiative"
    }
  },
  categories: {
    cat1: {
      id: "cat1",
      name: "Core",
      skillIds: ["skill1", "skill2", "skill3", "skill4"]
    },
    cat2: {
      id: "cat2",
      name: "Craft",
      skillIds: ["skill5", "skill6", "skill7", "skill8"]
    },
    cat3: {
      id: "cat3",
      name: "Leadership",
      skillIds: ["skill9", "skill10"]
    }
  },
  categoryOrder: ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"]
};
```

Function to update the `skillIds` array in the correct category

```
const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
    const result = Array.from(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);

    return result;
  };

  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const { source, destination } = result;

    // dropped outside the list
    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }

    // Handle moving within one category
    if (source.droppableId === destination.droppableId) {
      const catSkills = data.categories[source.droppableId].skillIds;
      const items = reorder(catSkills, source.index, destination.index);
      const newData = {
        ...data,
        categories: {
          ...data.categories,
          [source.droppableId]: {
            ...data.categories[source.droppableId],
            skillIds: items
          }
        }
      };
      setData(newData);
    }
  };
```

I've created a simplified codesandbox to test - https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-problem-il5m4

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the state is getting updated

```
 if (source.droppableId === destination.droppableId) { setData(data) }
```

this "if" clause means it will only update the state if the drag is happen on the same lane .i think you have tried to drag it to another lane . hope this is what you meant

Edit: I have understood your problem . The issue is you are not using updated data you are looping the static skill.I hope this solve your problem

```
      {data.categoryOrder.map((catId) => {
      const category = data.categories[catId]; //change skills to data
      const catSkills = category.skillIds.map(
        (skillId) => skills.skills[skillId]
      );
```

Comment: Hmm, well I suppose what I mean is that the drag action doesn't work, even when dragging on the same lane (see https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-problem-il5m4). Not sure whether that's 'state not being updated' or something else not updating the UI?

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! I was staring at the wrong bit of the code for so long!